# Alert prompt to function not working in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a button on my page that prompts an alert. If that user selects `Yes`, I then want the `exit()` function to run. However, the way it is coded now, for some reason nothing happens.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, Button, StatusBar, Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class IDScreen extends Component<Props> {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Identification',
  };

  exit = async () => {
    alert("I should see this but I don't");
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
  }

  promptExit() {
    Alert.alert("Are you sure?", "You can't be serious.", [
      {text: 'Yes, Sign out', onPress: async () => this.exit },
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    ],
    { cancelable: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.footerText} onPress={this.promptExit}>Sign Out</Text>
      </View>

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.exit` should be `this.exit()`. you need parenthesizes to execute a function

Comment: I then get `Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: _this3.exit is not a function` @bennygenel

Comment: change `promptExit` function to an arrow function or bind it in constructor. You are loosing context of `this` currently.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why that works, but it did! @bennygenel

Comment: You can read about more on binding and `this` in [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify  `promptExit()`  to an arrow function `promptExit = () =>`.

Arrow functions are used, **not to redefine the value of `this`** , inside their body, it simply means *same thing within the function body as it does outside of it.*

Since the function is called without its reference to a particular object, like `yourObj.yourMethod()`, therefore you either need to `bind` it in the `class constructor / render` or use `arrow function`.

Without it , it would lose it's context and will always be `undefined` or a `global object`.

Similarly, you can also read

> [When not to use arrow functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

**Try This method it Will Work**

*Invoke Alert.alert() function from Button, instead of calling Inside of another function, It will work, just see the code snippet.*
*And **exit** is an arrow function invoke like this **"this.exit()"** instead of **this.exit***.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
ActivityIndicator, 
AsyncStorage, 
Button, 
StatusBar,
Text, 
StyleSheet, 
View, 
TextInput,
Alert } from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class IDScreen extends Component<Props> {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Identification',
  };

  exit = async () => {
    alert("I should see this but I don't");
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.footerText} 
  onPress={
    () => Alert.alert(
       "Are you sure?", "You can't be serious.",
     [
      {text: 'Yes, Sign out', onPress: async () => this.exit() },
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), 
       style: 'cancel'},
      ],
    { cancelable: true });
  }

   }>Sign Out</Text>
    </View>

    );
  }

}
```