# Custom function in headerRight of StackNavigator in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component that I'm trying to have some left and right header buttons in the header area. However, I am having trouble getting my function `logout` to call. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it?

*I'm using react-navigation*

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { refreshing: false }
  }

  logout = async () => {
    alert("HI");
    AsyncStorage.setItem('current_appid', '');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Identification');
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor:"#fff", height:60},
    headerTitleStyle: { color:"#3F61E7", fontSize: 24},
    headerBackground: "#fff",
    title: 'My Title',
    headerRight: <Text style={{marginRight:15, color:"#3F61E7", fontWeight:"400", fontSize:16}}>Settings</Text>,
    headerLeft: <Text onPress={async () => this.logout} style={{marginLeft:15, color:"#3F61E7", fontWeight:"400", fontSize:16}}>Log Out</Text>
  };

}
```

Comment: Same mistake with the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591753/alert-prompt-to-function-not-working-in-react-native).. need parenthesizes.

Comment: I'm not seeing it @bennygenel :( - if you are referring to `navigationOptions`, I'm pretty sure it's supposed to an object according to `react-navigator`

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE :

In navigationOptions, you, and I quote grabbou on this [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/594#issuecomment-284636148) :

> You can't access state. What you can do is either use this.context, externalise props (parent component / redux) or see this thread [#145](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145)

And [dmhood](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145#issuecomment-281216897) :

> you can't call this.saveDetails() from a static context since the actual saveDetails method is a class method. You would need to make saveDetails static or just some helper function outside of the class.

One of the solution exposed in the #145 issue, and one that I used for an app that I am currently working on, is to use setParams on your componentDidMount lifecycle hook like so :

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({ yourfunction: this.yourfunction });
}
```

Then you can use the other way to declare your navigationOptions and this by declaring a function that takes in parameters the navigation object (with the navigation `state` (that contains the params !!))

( see an example on the main repo [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/2c7187b22aeff1cdec5ca6aeebb40c9c798c0888/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/SimpleStack.js#L176-L189))

```
  YourComponent.navigationOptions = props => {
      const { navigation } = props;
      const { state } = navigation;
      const { params } = state;
      return {
         /* your navigationOptions props */,
         headerRight: <Button onPress={() => params.yourfunction()} />
      }
  }
```

#### UPDATE 2 :

**If you want to stick with the other syntax, just remember that your headerRight component receives the navigation object as a props containing your navigation state and its params !**

#### UPDATE 3 :

A good discussion about how to solve this particular problem can be found on the official repo [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145#issuecomment-281216897)

Comment: I don't think you can use `:`. But even with the `=`, I've tried it all and it does not seem to be calling the function at all. If I do `this.logout()` it says it is not a function

Comment: Ah ! Sorry, wasn't aware of you using react-navigation, I will update my post soon, hint : it is due do the fact that you cannot access the instance within the navigationOptions

Comment: Damn okay. I'm looking forward to seeing your work around of how to access it

Comment: You can see a good topic to solve this problem here : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/145#issuecomment-281216897 (by the way, post updated)

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I followed everyones *solution* in here before I posted and wasn't able to get it to work unfortunately. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but to no avail so far. Who knew something such a simple function is SO COMPLICATED! lol

Comment: Wait a minute... can you use TouchableOpacity instead of a Text component ? it does not support the onPress props I guess

Comment: Also, try using this syntax : `headerRight: ({ navigation }) => TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.state.params.yourfunctionFromComponentDidMountSetParamsCall}><Text/></TouchableOpacity>

Comment: For all of these I am getting `Can't find variable: state`

Comment: can you console.log the props passed to your headerRight component ?